# Can TypeScript warn me about superfluous uses of the non-null assertion operator?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following TypeScript code:

```
let x = { foo: { bar: "baz" } };
console.log(x.foo!.bar);
```

Here, the inferred type of `x.foo` is `{ bar: string }`, and so there is no need for the use of the non-null assertion operator `!` (see e.g. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7395): the compiler *already* knows that `x.foo` cannot be null.

Can tsc (or possibly a widely-used third party tool like TSLint) warn me about these superfluous uses of `!`, and/or is this a planned feature?

I'm sure this is feasible in principle (seems like this'd just be a matter of using the TypeScript compiler API to identify places where `!` is used on variables whose type is not `T | null` or `T | undefined`); I'm just wondering if the heavy lifting has already been done. Or, I guess, a pointer to the relevant parts of the TypeScript compiler API would work too - it's tough finding documentation for it (I guess because it's not yet stable).

(The reason I ask is that I'm concerned that I'm going to end up having to deal with code where <s>past me</s> some idiot sprinkled `!` everywhere to make `tsc --strictNullChecks` stop issuing errors, without actually thinking about whether the asserted variable actually *will* be non-null at runtime. If it does end up null at runtime, voila! A bug that we could've caught at compile time, but didn't because of overzealous `!`. The presence of `!`s on variables already known to be non-null would strongly hint that the code is overusing `!`, likely incorrectly.)

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know this operator even existed.

Comment: Actually, there's nothing preventing you from doing this: x.foo.bar = null;
x.foo = null;, despite the fact that the type of x is { bar: string }

Answer (score 3):

TSLint does this now, via the [`no-unnecessary-type-assertion` rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-unnecessary-type-assertion/).

Code like this:

```
const x: string = "foo";
const y = x!.indexOf("f"); // <-- x is of type string; no need to assert non-null
```

Will trigger a warning something like this:

```
This assertion is unnecessary since it does not change the type of the expression.
```

Comment: Updated link: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unnecessary-type-assertion.md

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not seem like it currently can. In the interest of getting into the compiler codebase, I made it do so on my fork here: https://github.com/Sheeo/TypeScript/commit/e6d1651e4d28493b6e5f20d027ad8e86f7451552

You can run it by cloning the repo and using that version of the compiler -- remember to enable strictNullChecks :)